# What's the limit of Java 2D array length?

Tags: java, arrays, limit

I was doing boundary check of a 2D array which is `array[8][LIMIT];` Then I tried several times and found the `LIMIT` variable should not be larger than 89489404, otherwise there will be an exception like this:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at testLimit.testLimit.main(testLimit.java:9)`

I know that 2D array should be allocated the memory in continuous space but just out of curiosity, how do Java decide this number? If I need to `new` an 2D array based on user input, how do I check the boundary so that no `OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Maximum size of the array depends on how much Memory got allocated to JVM via -Xmx startup parameter. If you allocate more memory to the VM it can get more space allocated before running out of available memory. But absolute maximum is 2^31-1 since java uses signed integers and indicies have to be positive

Comment: Thanks for answering. So if I don't change the setting to VM, the max size should stay the same, can I assume that the max size should be 8* 89489404 for my case? And `array[x][y]` where x*y=8* 89489404 should be the limit?

Comment: should be the same +- a few elements depending on which Java version/implementation is used.